# How to use caffe to classify text?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm using the Rotten Tomatoes dataset to train my net. It's divided in two groups, positive and negative examples. How can I configure my cnn in caffe to predict if a given text is a positive or a negative example?
I already formatted the data, each sentence has a size of 56 words. But using the following config does not give me even a satisfactory result.

```
n = caffe.NetSpec()
n.data, n.label = L.Data(batch_size=batch_size, backend=P.Data.LMDB,
            source=db_path,
            transform_param=dict(scale= 1 / mean), 
            ntop=2)

n.conv1 = L.Convolution(n.data, kernel_size=3, pad=1, 
                        param=dict(lr_mult=1), num_output=10, 
                        weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))



n.pool1 = L.Pooling(n.conv1, kernel_size=n_classes, 
                    stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.MAX)

n.ip1 = L.InnerProduct(n.pool1, num_output=100, 
                       weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))

n.relu1 = L.ReLU(n.ip1, in_place=True)

n.ip2 = L.InnerProduct(n.relu1, num_output=n_classes, 
                       weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))

n.loss = L.SoftmaxWithLoss(n.ip2, n.label)
```

My dataset is divided in **two text files**. One containing the positives examples and other containing negatives examples. [Polarity dataset v1.1](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/). To organize my data I get the length of the biggest sentence (59 words) so if a sentence is smaller than 59 words I add some text to it. I adapted from [this code](https://github.com/yoonkim/CNN_sentence). For example, lets pretend that the biggest sentence has 3 words:

```
data = 'abc def ghijkl. mnopqrst uvwxyz. abcd.'

##
#In this data I have 3 sentences:
##

sentence_one = 'abc def ghijkl
sentence_two = 'mnopqrst uvwxyz'
sentence_three = 'abcd'
```

The `sentence_one` is the biggest (3 words), so to format the others two sentence I did the following:

```
sentence_two = 'mnopqrst uvwxyz <PAD>'
sentence_three = 'abcd <PAD> <PAD>'
```

Saved each positive and negative sentence to a caffe datum and saved in lmdb:

```
datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
datum.channels = 1
datum.height = 59 #biggest sentence
datum.width = 1
datum.label = label # 0 or 1
datum.data = sentence.tobytes()
```

Using my datum database and the above caffe's configuration I get a poor accuracy (less than 3 percent). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you encoding your text?

Comment: What result *do* you get?  Have you done anything to trace the processing?  Typically, we look for minimal code, expected result, and actual result, the canonical MCVE.

Comment: Are you using image text as an input, or raw text?

Comment: I edited my question, can you help me?

Comment: Caaarlos, have you tried to do something that Prune told you?

Comment: Pasdf and Prune, I'm sorry but I'm newbie. Can you explain me?

Comment: @Caaarlos: did you find your answer?

Comment: No, my friend used SVM with bag of words instead Caffe. His SMV got a good accuracy. Please, take a look on it: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html